# what does it mean to simulate the proposed transaction in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

what does it actually mean when we say endorsing peer simulates a proposed transaction. Why does endorsing peer needs to hold smart contracts to simulate proposed transaction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, keep in mind that the transaction flow works as follows:

1. The client sends a transaction proposal to some peers, with input parameters for the transaction, such as: "please move 20$ from alice to bob"
2. The peers run the transaction in the chaincode container, and afterwards sign the output of the transaction: "this is the new balance of alice, and the new balance of bob"
3. The client sends the transaction that contains the results and the signatures of the peers to the ordering service
4. The ordering service puts the transaction into some block
5. The peers pull the blocks from the ordering service or from other peers, and then commit the transaction (if it's valid) into the database.

Therefore, the transaction is not committed in the peers at the time of its execution, but instead - it's "simulated". Meaning - the peer runs the transaction in a simulation where the reads from the database are normal database operations that read data, but the writes to the database are not actually being written during the transaction execution - but instead, they are recorded as "simulation results" which the peer signs and returns to the client